# Display reply-to field in the inbox of Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I get a lot of emails from webadm@... They have the reply-to field set. I am interested in seeing this field. Is there a way to make thunderbird display it? I can choose fields to diplay but Reply-To seems not to be among them.

Comment: Just a comment, but I don't think this is possible without an add-on.

Comment: Maybe editing some file that is responsible for the fields. If there was an add-on, this would also be welcome.

Comment: Also for admin work, i'm also very interested in having a "Reply-to" column. The "choose which columns are displayed" enables to choose from a wide set of possible columns... but this required "Reply-to" option is not there !
You know a plugin that enables this ?

Comment: There was "columnWizard" extension that possibly might have enabled that, but it's not compatible anymore with current Tunderbird 91 version and not maintened https://github.com/micz/ColumnsWizard/issues/98